# Postgresql - CTE joining cte's and sorting

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have two CTE's in my sql file:

- First one finds the total_cost of a film in the inventory. If there is 8 DVD copies of a film in the inventory, and each costs $10, then it outputs 80 as total cost.
- The second one finds the total revenue of films. If a film was rented 20 times, and each rent is 5$, then it outputs 100 as revenue.
- Then using these CTE's I need to find the most profitable 10 films by calculating total_revenue - total_cost. total_cost and total_revenue work but the it doesn't work when I join them. There is a syntax error.

```
    /*TOTAL COST OF FILMS */

WITH total_cost AS (
  select  "films"."filmId",
          "films"."title",
          count("inventory"."inventoryId") as "numberOfCopies",
          sum("films"."replacementCost") as "totalCost"
  from    "films"
  join    "inventory" using ("filmId")

  group by ("films"."filmId");
  order by "totalCost" desc
  limit 10;
)

/* TOTAL REVENUE FROM FILMS */
WITH total_revenue AS (
  select    "films"."filmId",
            "films"."title",
            count("rentals"."rentalId") as "numberOfRentals",
            sum ("films"."rentalRate") as "totalRevenue"
  from    "films"
  join    "inventory" using ("filmId")
  join    "rentals" using ("inventoryId")

  group by ("films"."filmId");
  order by "totalRevenue" desc
  limit 10;
)

  select    "films"."filmId",
            "films"."title",
            "total_revenue"."totalRevenue" - "total_cost"."totalCost" as "profit"
  from "films"
  join "total_cost" using ("filmId")
  join "total_revenue" using ("filmId")
  group by "films"."filmId"
  order by "profit" desc
  limit 10;
```

Comment: please add a syntax error you get.

Comment: The error is not accurate. It says syntax error at the last line ";" . I know the problem is different. And there must be more than one mistake there.

Comment: remone semicolons from your CTE  expressions.